# Integrate MinGW with Visual Studio 2010 (Makefile Project)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, mingw, makefile

I'm trying to get MinGW (Version 4.7.2) working with Visual Studio 2010 to use some of the new C++11 features (sadly I'm still on WindowsXP and can't use Visual Studio 2012).
To get started, I created a project with:
File -> New Project -> Visual C++ -> General -> Makefile-Project

```
General:
Build Command Line: mingw32-make.exe
Rebuild All Command Line: mingw32-make.exe rebuild all
Clean Command Line: mingw32-make.exe clean all

IntelliSense:
Include Search Path: C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.2\include\c++;C:\MinGW\include;
Assembly Search Path: C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.2;C:\MinGW\lib;
Additional Arguments: -std=c++11
```

And I created an makefile with the content:

```
all:
    g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -o Makefile_Test.exe main.cpp
```

It compiles just fine, but almost everything is wavy red underlined in Visual Studios editor. i.e.

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
```

`std::vector` -> 'Error: namespace std has no member vector'

`std::thread` -> 'Error: namespace std has no member thread'

even `std::cout << "";`

`std::cout` -> 'Error: namespace std has no member cout'

But I included the correspondending headers of course: and Visual Studio can even find them (place the cursor at #include  -> Ctrl+Shift+G opens the header). My MinGw folder looks like the following:

```
+ MinGW
|- bin
|- doc
|- include
|+ lib
 |- gettext
 |+ gcc
  |+ mingw32
   |+ 4.7.2
    |- debug
    |+ include
     |- c++
     |...
    |- include-fixed
    |- install-tools
|- libexec
|- mingw32
|- msys
|- share
|- var
```

I also tried to delete the sdf file a few times and let Visual Studio rebuild it from scratch - but all these errors appeared again.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm afraid you will have to give up your attempts to make those red squiggles disappear *unless you disable them completely* (so that, for instance, not even calls to non-existing functions will be marked).

The reason is that [Visual Studio's Intellisense uses a separate front-end to EDG's C++ compiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/27/rebuilding-intellisense.aspx) to parse your program and possibly put a red squiggle under invalid statements or expressions, and the version used by Intellisense in VS2010 is (apparently) not fully compliant with C++11.

Therefore, switching to GCC 4.7.2 as the compiler will help building your C++11 programs, but won't affect the behavior of Intellisense.

If you want to disable the red squiggles completely, you can do it by selecting Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced, and setting "Disable Squiggles" to "True".

Comment: You're wrong. An errors `Error: namespace std has no member vector` `'Error: namespace std has no member cout'` surely don't belong to c++11. I am very curious what was the real problem that the Intellisense became screwed after @Constantin does such a pretty usual thing as changing a compiler of an IDE.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: The substance doesn't change: the OP is doing nothing wrong and the problem is with Intellisense and EDG's front-end, and the only way to make the squiggles disappear is to disable them altogether.

Comment: If I was the topicstarter, I'd next try to ask the Microsoft itself. At first on an MS forum. Next if the forum didn't helped, to ask the MS support(of course if @Constantin uses the licence version ;) ). And in the end I'd write an answer here. Because at the present moment here's a 3200 views, and I guess all those peoples were curious. Including me ☺

Answer (score 1):

Using the Makefile project template like OP described. I have been able to get VC 2013 & 2015 Community edition's intellisense working, by adding the proper include dirs to the projects properties.

1. Open the `Project menu`
2. Select `{Project Name} Properties`
3. Open the `Configuration Properties`
4. select `VC++ Directories` in the tree menu
5. Add Directories to the `Includes Directories` section

You do have to add the directories that contain the items you want read into intellisense. Say I am working on a gtkmm project, I'd also include the glibmm dir so the Glib::ustrings didn't get squiggles. Even if glibmm.h is not directly included in my source files.